# Как работать с русским алфaвитом в си?

Tags: c, utf-8, ascii

у меня есть небольшой csv файл, где присутствуют русские символы.
Я хочу вывести этот csv файл, но на выходе получается белиберда.

```
int main() {
    char buf[10000];
    FILE* table = fopen("/home/anton/project/semanalyzer/testfiles/test.csv", "rb");

    if (table) {
        fread(buf, sizeof(char), 10000, table);
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Как в си работать с русским алфовитом в си?

Comment: Дело не в русском алфавите, а в кодировке вашей ОС, или кодировке консоли в которую вы будете выводить ваши строки с русскими символами. Возьмите например библиотеку `ICU`, или `iconv`

Comment: странно, у меня выводит успешно, шаблон файла взял отсюда - https://itsm365.ru/documents_rus/web/Content/import/import_org_file.htm

Проверял на Линуксе, локаль стоит - en_US.utf8